# difference between JFrame.repaint() and JPanel.repaint()

Tags: java, swing

can please anyone explain the difference between `JPanel.repaint()` method and `JFrame.repaint()` method, i guess both calls the `paintComponent()` method in JPanel.

Please clarify, thanks

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Calling `repaint()` on any Component will add a request to the repaint manager to paint that component. If conditions are correct, the manager will then arrange to have the Component's `paint(...)` method called. Since a Component's paint method will then call `paintComponent(...)`, `paintBorder(...)` and `paintChildren(...)` this will have the component paint itself, its border and cascade painting recursively to all of its children, their children, their children's children, etc. Calling this on JFrame will cause this cascade to occur throughout the entire top-level window whereas calling it on a subcomponent will cause a repainting of that component and its children only.

Note that calling `repaint()` does not guarantee that the repaint manager will paint the component, especially if there are stacked requests.  For more on the details, please read [Painting in AWT and Swing](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html).

Answer (score 9):

**1.** When `repaint()` method is called then the **Event handler thread notifies all the components , and then every component calls their** `paintComponent()` **method.**

**2.** Calling `JPanel.repaint()` will have **all the component within the JPanel to** `repaint()`, and calling `JFrame.repaint()` will have **all the component within the JFrame to** `repaint()` .

**3.** Call **JFrame.repaint() to repaint the JPanel too without the need of JPanel.repaint()....**

Answer (score 1):

In brief,

- `JPanel.repaint()` will repaint itself and its children.
- `JFrame.repaint()` will repaint itself and its children. But since `JFrame` is the base, this will repaint every component within.

Check "@Hovercraft Full Of Eels" answer for details.