# setVisible() doen't takes effect instantly because JFrame waits for something

Tags: java, swing, jframe, actionlistener, actionevent

The sequence of execution that is happening is :
First I need to type correct password
Then JOptionPane msgBox pops out
I hit the "ok" button
then nothing happens in JFrame but as per the code under actionPerformed,the textField should be set visible.
I noticed that when I change the state of JFrame from maximise to minimise or visa versa then the textField becomes visible.
I need the JFrame to change instantly without waiting for any mouse event or since I haven't involved any.

```
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JPasswordField;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

public class GraphicItems extends JFrame{
    private JPasswordField password = new JPasswordField(10);
    private JTextField textField;

    public GraphicItems(){
        super("Graphics is fun");
        setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        textField = new JTextField("This secret will reveal after correct password");
        textField.setEditable(false);
        textField.setVisible(false);
        add(textField);
        add(password);

        HandlerClass theHandler = new HandlerClass();
        password.addActionListener(theHandler);
    }//end graphicItems constructor

    private class HandlerClass implements ActionListener{
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event){
            if(event.getSource()==password)
                if(password.getText().equalsIgnoreCase("kamal123")){
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"CorrectPassword","MessageBox",JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
                    textField.setVisible(true);
                }//end if
        }//end actionPerformed
    }//end HandlerClass
}//end graphicItems Class

public class MainClass{
    public static void main(String args[]){
        GraphicItems frameObj = new GraphicItems();
        frameObj.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frameObj.setSize(500,500);
        frameObj.setVisible(true);
    }//main method ended    
}//MainClass ended
```

Comment: *"..but as per the code under actionPerformed,the textField should be set visible."*  It is better not to play with the visibility of components.  The best approach here would be to create and add the component, then call `component.setEnabled(false)` until the condition is met..  Further tip, don't extend frame unless altering existing functionality.  Instead just use an instance of one.

Answer (score 1):

You must [`repaint()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Component.html#repaint()) your component in order to see changes, this is what is happening when you minimize and maximize your window.

Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11708678/difference-between-jframe-repaint-and-jpanel-repaint) to see correct way to use [`repaint()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Component.html#repaint())

Answer (score 1):

The actionPerformed is executed on the single AWT event handling thread.
During this time other events get no chance.
By postponing via **invokeLater()** you end the event handling fast, and allow the `setVisible` to work.

```
@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
    SwingUtilites.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            if (event.getSource() == password
                && password.getText().equalsIgnoreCase("kamal123")) {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,
                        "CorrectPassword", "MessageBox", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
                textField.setVisible(true);
            }
        }
    });
}
```